# Regex - URL links with two slashes

Tags: regex

I would like to write a very general regexp.

It's for:

```
/something/anything/example
```

Something, anything and example could be any words.
But not it should exclude:

```
/something/anything
```

Or:

```
/something
```

I know it's basic, but I couldn't find anything for that so far on Google.
Thank you!!
Tomi

Comment: did you want to match all the above strings?

Comment: In what language?, many offer utility classes to handle uris/paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic regex would be

```
^(\/[^\/\n]+){3}$
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/eF1xF7/1

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using JavaScript:

```js
var URL = "/something/hello/more"

var re = /\/[^/]+\/*/; // match a "/" then any characters except another "/" 
                      // then another "/" if there if it exists

alert(URL.match(re));
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, for something like **"/something"** it'd be more-like

```
import re
def fn(x):
    return re.findall(r'/[a-zA-Z]+',x)
```